# replace nulls separator in a text file with pipe separator

Tags: sed

I have a null separated text file with the data shown below

> 1111 AAA JOHN SMITH 34-35 City Road London SE20 3UA

I want to replace the Null separator with the PIPE separator

> 1111|AAA|JOHN SMITH|34-35 City Road|London|SE20 3UA

I have got 10 files with the similar format and I have to read each of the files and replace the null separator with pipe delimiter

I tried using sed command but no luck.

```
sed 's/\x0/|/g' $file > $DEST_DIRNAME/${newfile%.$ORIG_FILEEXT}.$DEST_FILEEXT
```

Comment: When you say "null separator", do you mean a space or the actual `\0` character?

Comment: the null separator is actual \0 character

Answer (score 2):

Given that you're doing a one character to one character mapping, `tr` is a much better fit for this.

```
tr '\0' '|' < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: much better than the awk answer I was just about to post.

Comment: Will the "tr" take care of "JOHN SMITH" as single character? I mean will "tr" add pipe separator in the middle of "JOHN|SMITH"  or will it add at the start and end of "|JOHN SMITH|"???

Comment: @3DM, what is in between JOHN and SMITH? Is it another null? Parsing names and addresses is not a trivial task.

Comment: @glennjackman. I am sorry. I should be more specific. I have got a ASCII NULL as separator and normal space between JOHN & SMITH.

Comment: then this is the solution you want. have you tried it yet?

Comment: @3DM - When I say `tr` works on a character-by-character basis, I mean it analyzes each character individually.  In this case, it'll look at the whole string, one character at a time and say "is this a NULL?  If so, make it a pipe, otherwise leave it alone"

Comment: Yes have tried it today and it worked. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @3DM - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!